# Question regarding finding of formulas for piecewise function composition

Tags: elementary-set-theory, function-and-relation-composition

I've encountered the following exercise that's giving me a lot of trouble:

> Let $X$ be a set. For any subset $A\subseteq X$, we can define a function $C_{A}:X \to \mathbb{Z}$ by:
>   $C_{A}(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1 \text{ if } x\in A\\
> 0 \text{ if } x\notin A
>  \end{cases}$
>   
>   
>   Find formulas for $C_{A \cup B}$, $C_{A \cap B}$, and $C_{\overline{A}}$ in terms of $C_{A}$ and $C_{B}$. Explain why your answer works.

My problem is that we know what $C_{A}$ is, but how do you find the value of $C_{B}$?

Answer (score 1):

The definition is not restricted for a particular subset $A$. It says, given *any* subset, which we call $A$ for the sake of this definition, we define a function which depends on that subset...

So $C_B(x)=1$ whenever $x\in B$, and $C_B(x)=0$ whenever $x\notin B$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So what format would my formulas generally look like? Would they also be piecewise?

Comment: Think what happens when you multiply two functions. What would the result be?